# SQL Select parent as column name and child as value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a database to store music.

There are different categories that each have sub categories. Example:

```
id    name                  parentID
1     instrumentation       null
2     solo_instrument       null
3     Concert Band          1
4     Brass Band            1
5     Fanfare Band          1
6     Clarinet              2
7     Saxophone             2
8     Trumpet               2
```

On the other hand I have a table that stores the musicID that is linked to a categoryID

```
id    categoryID  musicID
1     4           1
2     8           1
3     3           2
4     6           2
```

I need the following result from a query:

```
musicID    instrumentation    solo_instrument
1          Brass Band         Trumpet
2          Concert Band       Clarinet
```

I have been told to use a tree structure as in the future it is likely that other categories are added and this should be able to support that. However, I am not able to figure out how to write a query to get the result above.

I kind of get the result I want when selecting first the instrumentation, second the solo_instrument, but this is all hardcoded and does not allow for music tracks to only have one parentID as I select them individually.

Is this even possible or should I overhaul my database structure? I'd like to see your recommendations.

Comment: Well, one idea could be to switch to a nested set model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to tackle this using *conditional aggregation*.

Query :

```
SELECT
    mu.musicID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cp.name = 'instrumentation' THEN ca.name END) instrumentation,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cp.name = 'solo_instrument' THEN ca.name END) solo_instrument
FROM
    musics mu
    INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.id = mu.categoryID
    INNER JOIN categories cp ON cp.id = ca.parentID
GROUP by mu.musicID
```

The `INNER JOIN`s pull up the corresponding category, and then goes up one level to find the parent category. If new root categories are created, you would just need to add more `MAX()` columns to the query.

In **[this DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d8phQkCFF5wxdaFDWzGtDM/0)** with your sample data, the query returns :

```
| musicID | instrumentation | solo_instrument |
| ------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| 1       | Brass Band      | Trumpet         |
| 2       | Concert Band    | Clarinet        |
```

Answer (score 0):

First you group by musicid in table_music and the join twice to table_categories:

```
select t.musicid, c1.name instrumentation, c2.name solo_instrument
from (
  select musicid, min(categoryid) instrumentationid, max(categoryid) solo_instrumentid
  from table_music
  group by musicid
) t inner join table_categories c1
on c1.id = t.instrumentationid
inner join table_categories c2
on c2.id = t.solo_instrumentid
order by t.musicid
```